# trying to make image move using .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make an image move when the page loads by it self 
My main goal is to get the image to move in my desired directions so I can add walls and make it move and turn as soon as the page loads
Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
<img src="" class="maze" />
<img src="" class="player" />
</div>
```

```
body {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; }

.container {
 position: relative; }

.player {
position: absolute;
height: 5vh;
width: 5vh;
left: 40px;
top: 30px; }
```

/////
JavaScript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $( ".player" ).animate({ "down": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "left": "-=80px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "down": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "right": "-=30px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "down": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
```

});

Comment: You are selecting by the *class* `"player"`, but your element has the *id* `"player"`. And why are the `.animate()` calls *after* the document ready handler rather than *in* the ready handler?

Comment: My bad, still doesn't seem to move. I'm sorry. I'm just learning jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your (updated) code is that you are trying to make it move by animating the `"down"` property, but there is no such property. To make an element move down, add to its existing `"top"` property. To make an element move up, subtract from its `"top"` property.

Also, to make an element move to the right, add to its `"left"` property, don't subtract from its `"right"`, because you've set an initial `"left"` but not `"right"`.

In other words, having set the initial position by specifying the top-left, you would change the position by modifying the top and/or the left.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "top": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "left": "-=80px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "top": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "left": "+=30px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".player" ).animate({ "top": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

```css
img { border: thin black solid; } /* border added to make demo element visible */

.container { position: relative; left: 100px; }

.player {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5vh;
  width: 5vh;
  left: 40px;
  top: 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<img src="" class="maze" />
<img src="" class="player" />
</div>
```